# How do I call different values of each columns in my Mysql table with same invoice nº?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table named `purchase_details` with some values which has the same `invoice_no`. Now I need each of the data with the same `invoice_no` and output them in a input field which will the same amount of the `invoice_no` length.

As i am new to PHP I have tried to use an array but it's showing the letters of the last row.

[image: Here IS the table data i want to show]

```
<table align="center" style="width:800px;">
      <thead>
             <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Item Name</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Total Quantity</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Buy Price</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="invoice_item">
       <?php 
           $query1="select * from purchase_details where invoice_no=$id";
           $query1_run=mysqli_query($connect , $query1);
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1_run)){
               $product_name = $row['product_name'];
           }
           echo $product_name[0];
       ?>
           <tr>
               <td><b id="number"></b></td>
               <td>
                   <select name="pid[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
                       <option selected=""></option>
                   </select>
               </td>
               <td><input name="tqty[]" readonly type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" ></td>   
               <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" required value=""></td>
               <td><input name="price[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" readonly value=""></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end the while loop after the table data

```
<table align="center" style="width:800px;">
      <thead>
             <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Item Name</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Total Quantity</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Buy Price</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="invoice_item">
       <?php 
           $query1="select * from purchase_details where invoice_no=$id";
           $query1_run=mysqli_query($connect , $query1);
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1_run)){
               $product_name = $row['product_name'];

           echo $product_name[0];
       ?>
           <tr>
               <td><b id="number"></b></td>
               <td>
                   <select name="pid[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
                       <option selected=""></option>
                   </select>
               </td>
               <td><input name="tqty[]" readonly type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" ></td>   
               <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" required value=""></td>
               <td><input name="price[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" readonly value=""></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Yeah Just needed to add product_name[ ] = row['product_name']